# Why does the Main method have the word 'Overloads' in VB?

Tags: vb.net, keyword, program-entry-point

Coming from C#...

I was looking at this website

http://www.harding.edu/fmccown/vbnet_csharp_comparison.html

And noticed that it said

```
public static void Main(string[] args) {
```

is equivalent to

```
Overloads Shared Sub Main(ByVal args() As String)
```

So... what is that "Overloads" all about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a mistake, nothing is getting overloaded.  There is no pre-baked Sub Main() anywhere, especially not in a class named HelloWorld.  It happens to work because the vb.net compiler isn't very picky about it.  Paste this code in a class to see for yourself:

```
Class Test
    Overloads Sub IdontOverloadAnything()

    End Sub
End Class
```

The VB.NET compiler tends to make magic happen.  This is not one of those cases, the Main() magic is in the CLR.  Most any C# programmer would consider this a bug in the language.  I can't disagree.

Comment: So then just 'Shared Sub' would be sufficient?

Answer (score 2):

Because the standard Sub Main has no parameters and you are [overloading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ybxdk47f.aspx) it with the new Main procedure with parameters.

Answer (score 0):

In VB6, as in most "ancient" programming languages, there was the maxim "There can be only one!" (see the movie "Highlander"). You could have only one Function or Sub with the same name in a module or in a class. In VB.NET as in C# you can have several methods having the same name, as long as they have different signatures. This means that they need to have a different number of parameters or differnt types of parameters. These function are then said to be overloaded. In VB you can add the optional keyword `Overloads` to such Functions or Subs.

```
Public Sub Test(s As String)
Public Sub Test(i As Integer)
Public Sub Test(s As String, i As Integer)
```

This would be OK. However

```
Public Sub Test(t As String)
```

would not, since there exists already a overloaded method with one string parameter. Different parameter names are not sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Because there is a standard Shared Sub Main and you are overloading it. You can ommit the overloads.